# How can I run buildr with dependencied defined in pom.xml (buildr + eclipse + maven : integration)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, buildr

We are using buildr as the build tool for our projects.
However, it is time that dependencies a big in the several project we have and building new eclipse environments become a hard task.

The first I wanted to do is to have kind of eclipse project (.classpath & .project) generated from the build file, but the main problem is that it does not support stuff like Dynamic Web Project. Instead, buildr only generates simple project structure.

So, as next option, what I though about (since we don't want to change the actual build process) is to have the dependencies defined in maven's pom.xml files, that will define the actual project structure to be imported to eclipse. While BUILDR will continue to work as it is, but instead of reading its format for dependencies artifacts, it will read it from pom.xml or some other dependencies.xml file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unsupported, though you could always read the pom file using Ruby and extract the dependencies inline from it.

I personally commit in git our .project and .classpath files. I even commit our .settings file to deal with eols and have a set of formatters set in the same way for everyone.